# Hibernate event listener called too late in JUnit test

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit

We implement Hibernates `PreInsertEventListener` and `PreUpdateEventListener` to initialize and set the information who inserted and most recently changed an entity before saving it to the database. The fields containing this information are marked as not-nullable via JPAs `@Column(... , nullable = false)` annotation.

This setup worked fine, while we used Spring IO Platform Athens-RELEASE. Now we upgraded to Spring IO Platfrom Brussels-SR2 (the problem also occurs with Spring IO Platfrom Brussels-RELEASE) and our application is still behaving as expected/before (the entity is validated after the listeners have been called).

BUT ... our JUnit tests fail, because in the test setup Hibernate now first validates the fields and then calls the listeners. This order is ok when the entity is updated (the last-change-information was already set before) but causes an `org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value`-exception when the entity is inserted, because the fields are still null at the time of validation.

**Does anyone observe the same behaviour? Any ideas/suggestions on what is happening here and how to solve this problem?**

Some more background information:

- I know I could use JPA to handle PrePersist-Events but due to our project setup (and because we only observe the problem in the test setup, while our application is working fine) we would very much prefer a solution based on the already existing Hibernate Listeners (this mainly refers to [the answer given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178034/fire-hibernate-custom-event-listener-before-auto-triggered-default-listeners)).
- We use the Hibernate- and JUnit-Versions provided by Spring Platform (only hibernate-validator changed from Athens- to Brussels-RELEASE): hibernate-core: 5.0.11.Final (5.0.12.Final in Brussels-SR2), Junit: 4.12, hibernate-validator: 5.2.4.Final (Athens), 5.3.4.Final (Brussels), 5.3.5.Final (Brussels-SR2)
- We use DBUnit with version 2.5.3
- We register the listeners via `registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.PRE_INSERT).appendListener(...)`, replacing `appendListener(...)` with `prependListener(...)` doesn't help

Comment: You might want to take a look at hibernate envers. It does pretty much what you do, and even if you don't want to use it, you could see how they deal with this.

Comment: @wallenborn thanks for the hint. I had a look at it, directly using it would be a little bit too much for our current requirement but it was interesting to see that they register the listeners the same way we do...